# Instance error with vector when trying to generate random number

Tags: haskell, vector

I am trying to generate random number using `System.MWC` package. I wrote a small test code as below:

```
module Main where
import Data.Word(Word32)
import Control.Monad.ST as ST
import System.Random.MWC
import Data.Vector.Generic.Base
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as U

test :: Word32 -> Int
test x = runST $ do
      gen <- initialize (U.fromList [x] :: U.Vector Word32)
      v <- uniformR (1,100) gen
      return v
```

The problem is I am getting instance error when trying to use `initialize` function. This is the instance error I get:

```
    No instance for (vector-0.9.1:Data.Vector.Generic.Base.Vector
                       U.Vector Word32)
      arising from a use of `initialize'
    Possible fix:
      add an instance declaration for
      (vector-0.9.1:Data.Vector.Generic.Base.Vector U.Vector Word32)
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      gen <- initialize (U.fromList [x] :: U.Vector Word32)
    In the second argument of `($)', namely
      `do { gen <- initialize (U.fromList [x] :: U.Vector Word32);
            v <- uniformR (1, 100) gen;
            return v }'
    In the expression:
      runST
      $ do { gen <- initialize (U.fromList [x] :: U.Vector Word32);
             v <- uniformR (1, 100) gen;
             return v }
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I ran `info` in `ghci` to confirm that no instances are defined for `Data.Vector.Generic.Base.Vector`. I then checked `hackage` for documentation but no page exists for that package.

So, my question is where is that missing instance defined. I can load it once I know where it is defined. Importing `Data.Vector.Generic.Base.Vector` doesn't work. Also, `mwc-random-0.13.1.1` package has a dependency on `vector-0.9.1` as you can see in the error message above.

Comment: It works for me, but I did `gen <- initialize (U.fromList [x])`, since the extra type signature there is redundant.  I'm using mwc-random-0.13.1.0, and it actually depends on vector >= 0.7, so vector=0.9.1 is what you have installed on your system.  It should still work though.

Comment: @bheklilr, I added the type signature because of the error. Still, I get error but you don't, which is quite surprising.

Comment: I am using vector 0.10.0.1 and mwc-random 0.13.1.0, maybe you could try updating your version of vector to match?

Comment: @bheklilr, I have `vector 0.10.9.1` installed as well (as confirmed with `ghc-pkg`), but `mwc-random` seems to pick up `vector 0.9.1` instead. Removing `vector 0.9.1` and cabal re-install of `mwc-random` updated the dependency to `vector 0.10.9.1`, and fixed the issue. Can you post your suggestion (please mention cabal rebuild) as answer?

Comment: Glad it was a simple fix.  I've posted this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mwc-random` is picking an older installed version of `vector` rather than the latest one.  If you uninstall the older version of `vector` and reinstall mwc-random to pull the updated dependency of `vector-0.10`, then the issue resolves itself.

(Note: See the comment chain under the question for more details)

Answer (score 1):

The instances are defined one by one, individually per type.

http://code.haskell.org/vector/Data/Vector/Unboxed/Base.hs

Search for `#define primVector`. In particular, `primVector(Word32` should be the instance you're looking for.

I don't think this fixes your problem though.